# what do you call the feeling of pain addict have before using drug?

Tags: single-word-requests

when addicts don't use drug for a rather long time, they feel kind of angry and are in a bad mood. they also feel pain over their body I think(esp opium users.) what is that feeling or mood called?

Comment: If you look up addiction in any basic reference, it will explain *withdrawal symptoms*.

Answer (score 1):

Withdrawal symptoms or, colloquially, the DT's

Comment: Or *jonesing* if you want to be less clinical.  Although there is no real connotation of pain with *jonesing*- only need.

Comment: I thought “the DTs” were specifically a symptom of alcohol abuse (trembling hands) and not of withdrawal in general. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: [*Delirium tremens*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delirium_tremens), while primarily associated with alcohol withdrawal, is not exclusive to that drug.